# translating sql to SSIS expression builder

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

How to do the below in SSIS expression?

```
select REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(filename),CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(filename), 1) - 1))
```

Just stuck getting the filename but would want to do it in a package from the source in SSIS expression

Answer (score 1):

If we assume we have a whole path of the file `(eg. C\folder\filename...)` in a user variable `(eg. @[User::Variable])`, yuo can try with:

```
RIGHT( @[User::Variable], FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::Variable] ) , "\\", 1) - 1)
```

I hope this help.

Comment: that works however, i am getting the unicode to non unicode error. How would the syntax look to fix it please?

Comment: Error at Data flow OLE DB destination 384 column "FileName" cannot convert between unicode and non unicode

Comment: on the derived table it shows WSTR but the destination is varchar so would need to cast it

Comment: also why is there double back slash...? I cant test it until this casting thing is sorted first but is it suppose to be double backslash?

Comment: SSIS expression builder recognizes "\\" instead of "\" when indicating the path of a file.

Comment: In which part of the task or of the package do you have the error?

Comment: its in the dataflow as the target able is varchar but the derived column shows the data as nvarchar or WSTR

Comment: Add a Data Conversion item inside, so you can change type in column and pass correct type

Comment: Alright, so it can't be done on the expression? I will give the conversion a try but just seems like an extra step  rather than using the expression. Thank you Alex

Comment: `(DT_STR,255,1252)RIGHT(@[User::Variable],FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::Variable]),"\\",1) - 1)`   should work, I hope this help you (you can choose lenght 255, 1252 should be good for you).